# Relative path issue test cafe during file upload test using set files to upload()

Tags: testing, file-upload, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to validate a file upload using test cafe.the things are fine when I give absolute path of the file with in the t.setFilesToUpload() but when I give relative path its not finding the files and says could not find the required file. Can anyone help with this?

I tried using relative path of the file to be uploaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you validate file upload. Please refer to the related [help topic](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402808/recipes/basics/test-file-upload) in the TestCafe documentation. If you still have issues after reviewing it, please share an example that reproduces the issue.